# Help with derivation of equation of motion for a pendulum

Tags: derivatives, physics, classical-mechanics

I was reading about Lagrangian mechanics on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) and came across the equation for motion in the "Pendulum on a movable support" section and haven't been able to figure out where the $\dot{\theta}$ in the derivative for ${x_{pend}}$ came from. Intuitively, it makes sense that there is an angular velocity $\dot{\theta}$ term but I don't know how to derive it. The equation from the article is replicated below
$${x_{pend}} = x + l \, sin\,\theta \quad \Rightarrow \quad \dot{x}_{pend} = \dot{x} + l\dot{\theta}\,cos\,\theta$$

Thank you.

Comment: If we see $\theta$ as a function of time, then we have to apply the chain rule for differentiating $\sin(\theta(t))$ in time. This yields $\dot\theta(t)\cos(\theta(t))$. Or is that not what you're asking? I might misunderstand your question

Comment: 2nding: it's the chain rule. Both $x$ and $\theta$ are functions of $t$, and the dot means you're taking the derivative with respect to time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton's_notation).

Comment: @CPCH thank you both for deducing/pointing out that if we see $\dot{\theta}$ as a function of time, this is an application of the chain rule.
PS: Any hints on how I mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to regard $\theta$ as a function of time. Then the second term is just an application of the chain rule
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\sin(\theta(t))=\dot\theta(t)cos(\theta(t))$$